# git commit -a -m gives error for file not being tracked

Tags: git, commit, git-branch, git-commit, branching-and-merging

I am learning to work with git and I'm playing around with branching.
I created a file "test.rb" and committed a version on a 'testing' branch.

Being on 'master' I use `git commit -a -m 'msg'` and get this message:

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        test.rb

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I cannot understand why, since the '-a' flag should add everything to staging and commit it.

What am I missing?
Thanks !

Comment: `gives error` - that's not an error message. Untracked files are not automatically added using `-a` it's implied but not stated that's what you're expecting, can you edit the question to clarify please?

Comment: `git status` should tell you if you indeed have any other untracked files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since the `test.rb` file is not yet tracked by git, you need to add it
> first using `git add`

```
git add test.rb
git commit -m "msg"
```

After that, if you add changes to this file, you can use the `-a` option to commit your changes

```
git commit -am "msg"
```

This is also highlighted by the description for the `-a` flag in git's help:

```
$ git commit --help
-a, --all
           Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been
           modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about
           are not affected.
```